# Helm configuration file incorrectly used

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am a very beginner in helm so maybe this is a very trivial quiestion.
I using a toll which need a yaml file for configuration. I using some variable in the yaml file which variable comes from the values .yaml file.
The problem come up when I try to use helm install because that saying: 'Error: unable to decode "": Object 'Kind' is missing in'. I think it tries to use as a kubernetes yaml file. How can I skip this file to not use as a kubernetes config but include into the package because it used in a secret file with:
    '{{.Files.Get "config.yaml" | b64enc}}'.

Comment: Where did you place the `.yaml` file in the chart?

Comment: /templates/service/config.yaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything under `templates/` inside your chart is being interpreted as a k8s resource by helm. Try placing your static non-k8s files under another path, like `files/service/config.yaml`. Then you can use `{{.Files.Get "files/service/config.yaml" | b64enc}}` to place it inside your secret map.

In case you want to use templating inside that file, you have to take another approach and still place it under `templates/`, but define it inside a block via `{{- define "my_custom_block" -}}`:

**templates/service/config.yaml:**

```
{{- define "my_conf" -}}

Content ..

{{- end -}}
```

**templates/secret.yaml:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-map
type: Opaque
data:
  config.yaml: |
{{ include "my_conf" . | b64enc | indent 4 }}
```

Here some [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#know-your-template-functions) about the `include` statement.

Comment: ok but then I can not use {{.Values.service.whatever}} in the config file or is it possible in that case also ?